# Angular 11 reactive from error validation doesn't work

Tags: angular, validation

I am new in Angular. I am trying to learn it by doing. I tried reactive form validation as follows. It doesn't work. I can't see what is wrong:-

TS:-

```
export class LoanTypesComponent implements OnInit {

addLoanTypesForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.addLoanTypesForm =   this.fb.group({
      'loanName' : new FormControl('', [Validators.required,
      Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(4)]),
      'loanType' : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'terms' : new FormControl(),
      'loanDescription' : new FormControl()

  });
}
}
```

HTML:-

```
  <form [formGroup]="addLoanTypesForm">

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" formControlName="loanName"> <br/>
  <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.hasError('minlength') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.touched  ">This field minLength is 4 </div>
  <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.hasError('maxlength') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.touched  ">This field max length is 10 </div>
  <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.hasError('required') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.touched  ">This field is required </div>
</div>
<input type="text" formControlName="loanType"> <br/>
<div *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.hasError('required') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')?.touched  ">This field is required </div>
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="terms"> Accept Terms! <br/>
<textarea fromControlName="loanDescription"></textarea><br/>
<button [disabled]="!addLoanTypesForm.valid" (click)="addLoanType()">Add Loan</button>
```

I always only one error ***This field is required***. For min and max length validation never shows. As my submit button is disabled until the from is valid, I can see the button remain disable until I fill the condition. But the validation message never shows.  What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `loanType` has only `required` validations. `loanName` has a `min` and `max` validation. It will work fine if `addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')` is checked instead of `addLoanTypesForm.get('loanType')`.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenter wrote: "you mixed it up loanType with loanName, when you create validation messages in UI"

Solution is:

```
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')?.hasError('minlength') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')?.touched  ">This field minLength is 4 </div>
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')?.hasError('maxlength') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')?.touched  ">This field max length is 10 </div>
<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')?.hasError('required') && addLoanTypesForm.get('loanName')?.touched  ">This field is required </div>
```

If you wouldn't like to handled error messages manually i have a great package for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-form-validations

Try it, i hope like it.